# Lines inside svg file not appearing in visio

Tags: svg, visio, office-2013

I have been using Microsoft Visio 2013. I have imported some charts in SVG format into Visio, if I import bar chart, bars are coming fine, in line charts lines itself is not appearing and none of the charts appears with the axis lines(x-axis or y-axis). My SVG contains path elements.

Visio is not able to display this element:-

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M 41.1024 252.5 L 369.9216 
252.5" fill="none" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1" paint-order="fill" 
stroke-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-linecap="round" stroke- 
linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" clip-path="none"/>
```

nor this one:-

```
 <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M 41.1024 137.2126 L 123.3275 
 79.2266 L 205.6339 108.3963 L 287.8184 191.5267 L 369.9216 105.1593" 
 fill="none" stroke="#9b1e83" stroke-width="2" paint-order="fill" stroke- 
 opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke- 
 linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" clip-path="url(#zr9352-clip- 
 37)"/>
```

What should I do to make it appear in my MS-Visio?

Answer (score 0):

I think these are custom line/fill patterns. Visio does not handle these.